# Nodes in a flowchart with psmatrix environment

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

I'm trying to make a flowchart such as below in `psmatrix` environment using the `pstricks` package. but the problem is that I don't know how to make the node between the `{3-1}(num<=100)` and `{5-1}(num <- num + 2)`. I want to have my node as below:
[image]

But I have no idea how to make the above connection with `pst-nodes` or any other package! 
I checked out several documentations about `pst-nodes` but couldn't find anything. 
The code is:

```
 \documentclass{article}‎‎
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}‎ ‎
 \usepackage{pstricks}
 \usepackage{pst-node}
 \usepackage{pst-blur}
 \definecolor{‎Blue‎}{rgb}{1.,0.75,0.8‎}‎
    ‎
    % ================================
    % Source: http://tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/2009/006766.html

    \makeatletter
    \newdimen\psparallelogramsep
    \def\psset@parallelogramsep#1{\pssetlength\psparallelogramsep{#1}}
    \psset@parallelogramsep{3mm}
    \def\psparallelogrambox{\pst@object{psparallelogrambox}}
    \def\psparallelogrambox@i{\pst@makebox\psparallelogrambox@ii}
    \def\psparallelogrambox@ii{%
        \begingroup
        \pst@useboxpar
        \pst@dima=\pslinewidth
        \advance\pst@dima by \psframesep
        \pst@dimc=\wd\pst@hbox\advance\pst@dimc by \pst@dima
        \pst@dimb=\dp\pst@hbox\advance\pst@dimb by \pst@dima
        \pst@dimd=\ht\pst@hbox\advance\pst@dimd by \pst@dima
        \setbox\pst@hbox=\hbox{%
            \ifpsboxsep\kern\pst@dima\fi
            \begin@ClosedObj
            \addto@pscode{%
                \psk@cornersize
                \pst@number\pst@dima neg
                \pst@number\pst@dimb neg
                \pst@number\pst@dimc
                \pst@number\pst@dimd .5
                \pst@number\psparallelogramsep
                \tx@Parallelogram}%
                \def\pst@linetype{2}%
                \showpointsfalse
            \end@ClosedObj
            \box\pst@hbox
            \ifpsboxsep\kern\pst@dima\fi%
        }%
        \ifpsboxsep\dp\pst@hbox=\pst@dimb\ht\pst@hbox=\pst@dimd\fi
        \leavevmode\box\pst@hbox
        \endgroup%
    }

    % From the Frame and Rect PostScript macros
    \pst@def{Parallelogram}<{%
    /ParallelogramA {
    x1 pgs sub y1 moveto
    x1 y2 lineto
    x2 pgs add y2 lineto
    x2 y1 lineto
    x1 pgs sub y1 lineto
    closepath} def
    %
    /pgs ED
    CLW mul
    /a ED
    3 -1 roll
    2 copy gt { exch } if
    a sub
    /y2 ED
    a add
    /y1 ED
    2 copy gt { exch } if
    a sub
    /x2 ED
    a add
    /x1 ED
    1 index 0 eq {pop pop ParallelogramA } { OvalFrame } ifelse}>
    \makeatother

    \def\pspbox[#1]#2{\makebox[#1]{\psparallelogrambox{#2}}}

    % ================================
    \pagestyle{‎empty}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

    ‎\begin{‎document}‎‎
    ‎
    ‎\vspace{0.5cm}
    ‎\small‎
      \psset{shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90,blur=true}‎
      \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.7]% defines the distance between two frames 
       %Begin‎‎
        ‎\psovalbox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=‎yellow!30‎]‎{Start} \\
       %computation‎
        \psframebox[shadow=true]{‎$‎Sum ‎\Leftarrow 0 ‎,‎‎ Num ‎\‎leftarrow ‎10‎‎‎$}  ‎\\‎
       %Condition‎
        \psdiabox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=magenta!20]{‎‎$‎Num ‎\leqslant ‎100‎ ‎‎$‎} &
       %Output‎‎
        ‎‎‎\psparallelogrambox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=‎blue!20‎]{‎Print Sum‎} ‎\\‎‎ 
       ‎%Computation‎
       ‎ \psframebox{‎‎‎$‎Sum ‎\l‎eftarrow ‎Num + Sum ‎‎‎$‎} ‎&‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
      ‎%End‎
      ‎  \psovalbox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=yellow!30]{‎End}‎\\‎
      %computation‎‎
         ‎\psframebox{‎‎‎$‎Num ‎\l‎eftarrow ‎Num + 2‎‎‎$‎}‎‎\\‎
      % Links
        \ncline{->}{1,1}{2,1}
        \ncline{->}{2,1}{3,1‎}‎‎‎ 
        \ncline{->}{3,1}{4,1}<{\textcolor{red}{‎Yes‎}}‎‎ 
        \ncline{->}{4,1}{5,1}‎‎
        \ncline{->}{3,1}{3,2}^{\textcolor{red}{‎No‎}}‎‎
        \ncline{->}{3,2}{4,2} ‎‎
        % I‎ ‎used ‎these ‎two ‎but ‎none ‎of ‎the‎m were helpful 
         \ncdiag[angleA=-90,angleB=‎18‎0, armA=1cm,armB=1cm,‎lineAngle=-‎3‎0]{->}{5,1}{‎3,1}‎‎
        ‎%‎ \nccurve[ angleA=-90,angleB=180]{->}{5,1}{3,1}    ‎‎
 \end{psmatrix} ‎‎‎‎

 \end{‎document}‎
```

But the shape which I get is: 
[image]

So which command should I use in order to get the right nodes for this flowchart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the connection `ncangles` In the example below I removed the defintion of `\psparallelogrambom` and use instead `\psframebox` to simplify the example.

For more information to this command have look at the documentation of [pst-node.](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-node)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{1,0.75,0.8}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
 ‎\vspace{0.5cm}
 ‎\small‎
  \psset{shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90,blur=true,fillstyle=solid}‎
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.7]% defines the distance between two frames 
    \psovalbox[fillcolor=yellow!30]{Start} \\
    \psframebox[shadow=true]{$Sum \Leftarrow 0 , Num \leftarrow 10$}\\
    \psdiabox[fillcolor=magenta!20]{$NUM\leqslant100$}&
    \psframebox[fillcolor=blue!20]{Print Sum} \\
    \psframebox{$Sum \leftarrow Num +Sum$} &
   \psovalbox[fillcolor=yellow!30]{‎End}‎\\‎
   \psframebox{$Num \leftarrow Num +2$}  \\

   \psset{arrows=->,fillstyle=none}
        \ncline{1,1}{2,1}
        \ncline{2,1}{3,1}
        \ncline{3,1}{4,1}<{\textcolor{red}{Yes}}
        \ncline{4,1}{5,1}
        \ncline{3,1}{3,2}^{\textcolor{red}{No}}
        \ncline{3,2}{4,2}
        \ncangles[angleA=-90,angleB=180,armA=1cm,armB=1cm,lineAngle=-30]{5,1}{3,1}

 \end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]